# Connecting external HDMI monitor from type-c laptop

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display, usb-c

today I received type-c adapter (bought this one: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001596762329.html)

I connected this usb type-c to HDMI adapter using type-c port which charges laptop and connected my monitor to HDMI port which is in adapter, but then nothing happens, my laptop doesn't detect new monitor at all. I tried 2different monitors and both work fine if I connect using HDMI port which is on left side of laptop but I need to have 2external monitors so I bought adapter but it's not detecting, how should I solve this issue? Really need to have 2additional displays.

My Xiaomi laptop is: Xiaomi Mi Laptop Pro 15.6 inch Intel Core i7-10510U NVIDIA GeForce MX250 16GB DDR4 RAM 1TB SSD

I also tried to use this adapter with my old xiaomi air 12 laptop and it's working perfectly fine from type-c port I can connect adapter & hdmi monitor and laptop detects it 1440p 60hz..

Comment: If you right click on your desktop background and open up the Nvidia control panel, do you see the diagram that shows what ports are connected to your GPU

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/PKJgIE4.png

I get this, my laptop has NVIDIA MX250 and Intel UHD graphics, I think if connecting via HDMI port which is on left side it connects via NVIDIA MX250, but if using type-c on right side it would use intel UHD graphics with better max resolution, would really appreciate futher assistance @lost_admin

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WZD3I4L.png

Found it, I don't have any monitor connected now tho, let me know what I should change there

Comment: That's interesting, usually with USB-C you will see a USB-C port there (regardless of something being connected). Next to the physical port on the side of your computer, does it have a lightning bolt symbol?

Comment: IT does not, it just got led which lights up when laptop is charging together with 2 usb-c ports, attaching pictures of ports: https://imgur.com/a/U6WcNCS

Answer (score 0):

<strike>After doing some research, I believe you can find some more information [here](https://techtablets.com/forum/topic/notebook-pro-15-6-usb-c-to-dp-4k-60hz-monitor/). It suggests that a specific adapter is needed for this. It does seem to be a common issue with that model of your machine.</strike>

After further troubleshooting, unsure of solution

Comment: well I checked that thread but the problem they were facing is because they needed 4k@60hz and other adapters were only doing 30hz or lower resolution, in my case I don't get display detected at all but on xiaomi air 12 laptop this same adapter works perfectly fine, so I don't think there is a problem with adapter, but problem is with my laptop

Comment: @marciakas Do you see device manager refresh when you plg/unplug the monitor?

Comment: @marciakas https://www.androidkosmos.de/test-xiaomi-mi-notebook-pro/#Mi_Notebook_Pro_8211_Treiber_Driver_download im thinking it may be a drivers issue, the two zip files on this page should contain the required drivers for it -- worth a shot. If not, it could be an issue with HDCP2.2 in which case you may need a USB-C to Display port adapter instead. Just trying to trouble shoot, i apologize that this is becoming such a headache!

Comment: thanks for your help, really appreciate it, so I did those things to check if device manager refresh:
1. Plugged in/out to laptop left side HDMI - device manager refreshed
2. Plugged in/out adapter to type-c - device manager refreshed
3. Plugged in/out monitor to adapter, while it's connected to type-c, device manager did NOT refresh

Will try to install those driver packages now and see how it goes

Comment: Atleast it is recognizing that the adapter is being plugged in! Let me know how the drivers go :)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/oIewAky.png
https://i.imgur.com/G4V9iaQ.png

both intel and nvidia drivers got me errors, but I installed other drivers including USB.

Will restart computer and see if anything changed

Comment: sounds good. also can you share a screenshot of your device manager too

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/IUptap0.png

Still same, monitor not giving any signs when connected :( Let me know if I should expand smth else in device manager screenshot

Comment: unfortunately, im at a complete loss. the only thing i can think of that it might be is that the port on your computer is not compatible with passing video over the hdmi adapter and may need to use displayport. its very strange.

Comment: thanks for your help anyways, I will try to get another adapter and see if it works, just may take a few days

Comment: of course! good luck man